# All signed txs get reverted when interacting with testnet

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to call a contract deployed on Rinkeby. When I'm deploying it with truffle and interacting with any function it works, but with web3 I always get a revert. I use the following code:

```
var web3 = await getWeb3(network, "http");

var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(pubKey);

const txParams = {
  "from": pubKey,
  "to": instance.address,
  "data": instance.methods
          .swapEtherToToken(token, amount, customer)
          .encodeABI(),
  "value": "0x0",
  "gas": DEFAULT_GAS_LIMIT,
  "nonce": nonce,
  "chainId": 4,
  "gasPrice": DEFAULT_GAS_PRICE
};

  var transaction = new EthereumTx(txParams);

  const privateKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex');

  //signing transaction with private key
  await transaction.sign(privateKeyBuffer);

  //sending transaction via web3js
  web3.eth
  .sendSignedTransaction('0x' + signedTx.serialize().toString('hex'))
  .on('receipt', (receipt) => {

    console.log("Swapped ether to " + token + " for " + customer);

  })
  .on('error', (error) => {console.log(error)})
```

I followed multiple articles but all of them used approximately the same technique.

What do I do wrong?